# Check if name already exist in database before adding in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, database, laravel-4

Laravel 4.2 newbie here! I have this code in my controller

```
public function store()
{
    //
    $rules = array(
        'name'   => 'required|min:2|max:20|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/',
        'stock'  => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        'origin' => 'required|min:5|max:200'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('weapons/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        // check first if the name exists already then store
        $weapon = new Weapon;
        $weapon->name   = Input::get('name');
        $weapon->stock  = Input::get('stock');
        $weapon->origin = Input::get('origin');
        $weapon->save();

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created nerd!');
        return Redirect::to('create');
    }
}
```

I need to check whether the name already exists in the database; how can I do this?

Can I declare a new function inside the controller? Please help.

Comment: You can validate in your rules

Comment: How about just making field unique in database structure? Then you will get "duplicate index" message when trying to insert same name again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate that already in your rules:

```
 $rules = array(
    'name'   => 'required|min:2|max:20|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/|exists:TableName,name',
    'stock'  => 'required|numeric|min:1',
    'origin' => 'required|min:5|max:200'
);
```

Comment: Thanks guys! appreciated! :)

Comment: Maybe a green check for this? :D